# animating pseudo element when passing to another element

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I got a pseudo-element that marks the user's current choice in a navigation bar. It's a small upward triangle, an icon font from Font-Awesome. [here's a jsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4qVU4/5/) of it (you need to stretch the result panel so everything will be lined).

[image]

```
.subnav > ul > li.active > a:after {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  top: 25px;
  right: 50%;
  content: "\f0de";
  color: #c1c1c1;
}
```

I've added some basic jQuery function that switches the `.active` class, and I'm wondering if there's a way to animate the transition of the pseudo element so it'll move horizontally to the new position.

I know pseudo-elements transition are a thing, but searching and googling around I couldn't find anything similar to what I'm looking for. Is this even possible?

Comment: Yes, there's a way but the :after element should be given to the <ul> instead of the single li > a > i

Comment: Right now, when the page loads, the little arrow belongs to the first li > a > i, but what happens when you click on "users"? the :after will still be in the first li. You should move it to the ul and then use javascript to see where exactly it needs to go (by finding the active item and transition the arrow to its position)

Comment: @JonasGrumann I'm actually building a demo with this exact solution :)

Comment: ok, in that case I won't do it ;)

Comment: @JonasGrumann Ok! The main problem is that pseudo-elements aren't accessible directly in JS... I'm thinking about using a real element, any suggestion?

Comment: However, you should not be using a pseudo-element to achieve this. Just add an absolute `span` which will be way more easy to handle with.

Comment: @JonasGrumann I thought about that, but as Bigood pointed out, you can't control pseudo elements through js. How do you calculate the right position with the js and pass that information to the `:after` css?

Comment: That's true, you can't access pseudo elements. I think your best bet would be a span element for your arrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this solution I used the `:target` pseudo class to switch states, but I recommend you stick with the  jQuery function that switches the .active class.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/9SxSA/7/)**

### Markup

```
<div class="page" id="one">page one</div>
<div class="page" id="two">page two</div>
<div class="page" id="three">page three</div>

<div class="top">
    <div class="arrow"></div>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#one">One</a></li>
        <li><a href="#two">Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#three">Three</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.top
{
    background: #eee;   
    position:relative;
    overflow: hidden;  
}
.arrow
{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c2c2c2;
    height: 50px;

}
.arrow:before
{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    border: 1px solid #c2c2c2;
    border-radius: 3px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-9px;
    left: 30px;
    background: #fff;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg); 
    transform: rotate(45deg);

    -webkit-transition: left, 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: left, 0.5s;
    -o-transition: left, 0.5s;
    transition: left, 0.5s;
}
ul
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
li
{
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #676767;
    margin-right: 40px;
}
.page
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
    opacity: 0;
    background: yellow;
    -webkit-transition: opacity, 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: opacity, 0.5s;
    -o-transition: opacity, 0.5s;
    transition: opacity, 0.5s;
}
.page:target
{
    opacity: 1;
}

#two
{
    background: pink;
}
#three
{
    background: brown;
}
#one:target ~ .top .arrow:before
{
    left: 30px;
}
#two:target ~ .top .arrow:before
{
    left: 105px;
}
#three:target ~ .top .arrow:before
{
    left: 189px;
}
```

Comment: when you say "stick with the jQuery" do you mean I should do the animation through jQuery too?

Comment: No, just the logic of adding/removing the .active class needs to be done with JQuery

Comment: Alright, I got it. Thanks a million man! This is perfect. Here's a final [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4qVU4/7/).